# How can I stop the use of my images on another website?

Tags: php, image, .htaccess, security, client-server

Suppose I am showing my images on my server (www.myserver.com) like below:

```html
<img src='http://www.myserver.com/users/images/example.jpg' alt='example' />
```

The above image should be shown because it is on my server but in the case that the same *html* is served from a different host, for example: www.otherserver.com - I don't want the image to be shown.

Can anyone detail how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using apache then you can stop hot linking through htaccess.
See here is complete guide to this.
http://altlab.com/htaccess_tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use http-server (nginx or other) for your case
You can create new routem for example:

```
location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$ {
    valid_referers none blocked www.myserver.com myserver.com;
    if ($invalid_referer) {
        return 403;
    }
}
```

Docs for nginx - http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_referer_module.html#valid_referers